# Symfony custom bundle with route & basic auth

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'd like to create a custom bundle that provides a route, which should be secured by basic auth.

That is an easy case in Symfony itself. But I want a user to be able to install my bundle and have the route and basic auth set by the bundle automatically. The credentials for the basic auth can be added in a .env for example.

Is this even possible? Because I found this:

> Routing is never automatically imported in Symfony. If you want to include the routes from any bundle, then they must be manually imported from somewhere in your application

(https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#routing)

Does this mean my bundle can provide the route, but the user has to add it manually to `config/routes.yaml`?
And what about the security.yaml?

```
my-bundle
 - src
 -- Resources
 --- config
 ---- routes.yaml
 ---- security.yaml
```

Comment: Typically you would instruct the users to add a resource line to routes.yaml which in turn would pull in your bundle's route.  Take a look at config/routes/dev/web_profiler.ymal for an example.  If you got really fancy then you could create a recipe that would copy a routing file from your bundle to config/routes where it would get picked up.  But that is something you could consider doing later.

Comment: It is possible - for example, ApiPlatform does it like configured in https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/master/api-platform/admin-pack/1.0